# 404 error on page reload

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, javascript

I have created a WordPress based web app that will rely on template pages that will host some vue.js different front-end apps. I've added this code to the theme functions file to rewrite all the requests to the `index.php` file that is the front-controller of each WordPress installation

```php
// Redirect all requests to index.php so the Vue app is loaded and 404s aren't thrown
function remove_redirects() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^/(.+)/?', 'index.php', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'remove_redirects' );
```

_I've noticed that if I try to reload the registration page, I will always get a 404 error so I need to go back to the home of the website and then click on the registration button I have into the page. Is there any fix I can apply? The registration page is managed by vue router with this code

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
//
import UserLanding from '../components/UserLanding.vue'
import UserRegistration from '../components/UserRegistration.vue'

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(window.location.pathname),
    routes: [
        {
            name: 'UserLanding',
            path: '/',
            component: UserLanding
        },
        {
            name: 'UserRegistration',
            path: '/registration',
            component: UserRegistration 
        }
    ]
})

export default router
```

Thank you for the support

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule` isn't a redirect, what you're doing here is the equivalent of putting `query_posts([]);` into WordPress core at a very early point then commenting out the main query code. WP parses the ugly permalinks that take the form `index.php?queryvar=value` and rewrite rules are used to convert pretty URLs like `/foo/bar` into `index.php?foo=bar` but no actual redirects or file changes are happening, it's just for figuring out query variables for the main query. Any resemblance to HTAccess type stuff is purely coincidental

Comment: Is there a possible solution to this?In my case I don't need to change file but simply let know to the vue app that needs to reload the page

Comment: assuming you're resaved permalinks what do the rewrite rule testing plugins say when testing the `/registration` URL, have you considered creating dedicated pages or rewrite rules for those?

Comment: I don't have a dedicated page due to the nature of Vue app that is a single page. How I can rewrite the url?

Comment: you can create a page with that name as a workaround until you solve your rewrite rules problem. Have you tested the URL in a rewrite rule tester plugin to see if it matches your rewrite rule or if something else matches it? Even if it worked you'd still get HTTP 200 for pages that your vue application insist don't exist. It would be sensible to make sure that pages that are important to your Vue app also exist in WP if not for the sake of rewrite rules but for REST API and sitemap purposes. Also my understanding suggests that if your rewrite rule did work it would break the REST API too

Comment: From what I understand of how rewrite rules work, for you specific use case `add_rewrite_rule` cannot be used like that, the closest to your code you can get would be to register rewrite rules for all the pages that only exist in your Vue application, aka create virtual pages, but a rule that makes all URLs not 404 won't work as it would have to be the lowest priority and the pages rewrite rule or another will intercept it. Making it the highest priority will break things, e.g. the REST API which uses pretty permalinks for endpoints, or sitemaps

Comment: also, have you considered loading your vue application on 404 pages too?

Comment: No, I didn't considered to load the vue app in 404 page. It will not exist in the theme that will only have page templates for the main and other small vue apps. I can create a page in wordpress named registration, but not sure if will load vue correctly. Is there any other topc with a similar issue?